# Postgraduate medschool

Tags: university, united-kingdom, medicine, india

If an undergraduate in medicine and surgery(MBBS) from India wants to practice in UK, the person will have to register with NHS after the licensing exam. And after that the student is put through FY1+FY2 or directly speciality training. And the student will work in the hospital and simultaneously give exams to start working as a consultant.

In India, there's a completely different process. After undergraduation, the student gets licensed as a doctor after which the student does a speciality by enrolling for a postgraduate course at a university.
And attends patients during the postgraduate course just like during the undergraduate course.

If you notice the difference I'm trying to point out...
I want to understand about the following:

1. What would be the difference between the speciality training in UK and a postgraduate in India?
2. Why are there not many similar postgraduate courses available at UK universities? (Like it's more of research or only partially-taught courses. It's not like India i.e. fully-taught.)
3. Will I be missing out on something if I choose to enroll for speciality training in the UK instead of the postgraduate in India?

Comment: If you want to practice medicine in some country (as opposed to medical research) life is much easier if you get your education in _that_ country.

Comment: Do you know if there is a specific reciprocity agreement for medical workers between India and UK? There might be, given the history. But countries are very fussy about the training of doctors.

Comment: @Buffy I was digging through a lot of YouTube videos and found one which explains the exact difference between the speciality training and the postgraduate. It's just that in India the speciality training is integrated into the postgraduate unlike UK where the speciality training is just a training programme with a hospital during which you have to sit for membership/fellowship exams and successfully pass certificate exams.

Comment: I don't think any of that matters. What matters is what will be accepted in UK if you train in India. You need to get that question answered. I suspect there will be problems. Some doctors from other countries drive taxis in the US since their medical degrees aren't recognized. If lucky they practice as nurses. It is a problem generally.

Comment: I don't know about moving to the UK to practice medicine, but I do have some personal friends and their spouses who have tried to practice medicine in the US with medical training elsewhere, in well-respected systems (UK and Israel), and they had quite a few hoops to jump through. It's a mess. I don't think YouTube is a good place for information, and I don't think we have many people familiar with the medical profession here on Academia.SE. You need very direct advice from someone who has actually gone through this process, and even that may be contaminated by selection bias.

Comment: In answer to 2) it's because junior doctors in the UK (i.e. F1 and F2) rotate through various specialisms over the two years before deciding which to focus on. Postgraduate study in medicine is focused on medical research, not clinical practice. But info this is all anecdoctal (I have a good friend who is in her F2 year now) -- as the others say, you need to seek specialist advice.